# Insert whole HTML code into content table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update the intro field of the content DB (Joomla) with a whole HTML code which is about 1200 lines long.

```
try {
        $MyDBConn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=$MyDBName", $MyDBUser, $MyDBPass);
        // PDO can throw exceptions rather than Fatal errors, so let's change the error mode to exception
        $MyDBConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        //$MySQL = "UPDATE jso_content SET introtext = '$MyTeamHTML_FR' WHERE titel like '%$MyTeamTitel' and alias like '%$MyTeamAlias'";
        $MySQL = "UPDATE jso_content SET introtext = :INTRO WHERE alias = :ALIAS";
        $MyStmt = $MyDBConn->prepare($MySQL);
        $MyStmt->execute(array(':INTRO' => $MyTeamHTML_FR, ':ALIAS' => $MyTeamAlias));
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage()."\n";
    }
    $MyDBConn = null;
```

The update does not perform tough and I don't know why.
When I do this manually through PHPMyAdmin, I can insert the text code.

I used the same statements in a post before and this got solved as there was an error while using exec() instead of execute().

Another comment was on SQL injection attacks, which I hope I solved.

Thank you for your support

Regards

Laurent

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: What's the result of `execute()`?

Comment: I see no error. the script passes..

Comment: A problem is, I'm on a hosted server and I do not have SSH access, so I only can put my php file and execute it from the scheduler. Here everything is Green, so good, at least I guess

Comment: Task "scripts/bin/import_fltt.php" successfully completed in 7 seconds, output:

Comment: What type of http request are you using? Have you verified the server received the request? What about the form, have you checked?

Comment: I have 2 othee SQL statements in the same script running with success.The scripts runs on the hosting server...here are the statements that run. the connect and prepare is exactly the same...: $MySQL = "UPDATE jos_jsn_users SET grading = :RANKING WHERE fltt_license like :LICENSE";
      $MySQL = "UPDATE jos_jsn_users SET grading_points = :RANKINGPOINT WHERE fltt_license like :LICENSE";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for that post. I realized later last might, that I had a typo here in

```
"UPDATE jso_content SET introtext = :INTRO WHERE alias = :ALIAS"
```

this should bw

```
"UPDATE jos_content SET introtext = :INTRO WHERE alias = :ALIAS"
```

After changing it, the scripts passed.

Anyway, thank you for your comments
Cheers
Laurent

Answer (score 0):

I change your code a little and added code for logging the exception. This will help you debug in case of error and solve it.

```
try {
    $MyDBConn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=$MyDBName", $MyDBUser, $MyDBPass);
    // PDO can throw exceptions rather than Fatal errors, so let's change the error mode to exception
    $MyDBConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //$MySQL = "UPDATE jso_content SET introtext = '$MyTeamHTML_FR' WHERE titel like '%$MyTeamTitel' and alias like '%$MyTeamAlias'";
    $MySQL = "UPDATE jso_content SET introtext = :INTRO WHERE alias = :ALIAS";
    $MyStmt = $MyDBConn->prepare($MySQL);
    $MyStmt->execute(array(':INTRO' => $MyTeamHTML_FR, ':ALIAS' => $MyTeamAlias));
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    $h = fopen('<path_to_a_writable_dir>/error.log', 'a+');
    fwrite($h, var_export($e, true));
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage()."\n";
}
$MyDBConn = null;
```

Make sure to pass writable dir for `path_to_a_writable_dir`

Comment: I know. logging is my weak point, even if I wabt to, I forget... :-)